# Why I can't navigate between to pages when I use aggregate instead of find?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

At first I used

```
module.exports.getForums = async (req, res) => {
    const { page } = req.query;
    try {
        const LIMIT = 6;
        const startIndex = (Number(page) - 1) * LIMIT; // get the starting index of every page
        const total = await Forum.countDocuments({});
        const forums =  await Forum.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(LIMIT).skip(startIndex);
        //console.log(Forum);
        res.status(200).json({ data: forums, currentPage: Number(page), numberOfPages: Math.ceil(total / LIMIT) });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

this means that I can display 6 forums per page and this is how it looks like:
the first page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MyRF.png)
the second page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwxWY.png)

then I needed to use aggregate instead of find like this:

```
module.exports.getForums = async (req, res) => {
    const { page } = req.query;
    try {
        const LIMIT = 6;
        const startIndex = (Number(page) - 1) * LIMIT; // get the starting index of every page
        const total = await Forum.countDocuments({});
        const forums =  await Forum.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "comments",
                    let: { forumid: "$_id" },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $eq: ["$forumid", "$$forumid"],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            $project: {
                                _id: 1,
                                comment: 1,
                                createdAt: 1,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    as: "comments",
                },
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "answers",
                    let: { forumid: "$_id" },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $eq: ["$forumid", "$$forumid"],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            $project: {
                                _id: 1,
                                //comment: 1,
                                //createdAt: 1,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    as: "answersDetails",
                },
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    __v: 0,
                },
            },
        ]).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(LIMIT).skip(startIndex);
        //console.log(Forum);
        res.status(200).json({ data: forums, currentPage: Number(page), numberOfPages: Math.ceil(total / LIMIT) });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

now it only display 6 forums per page and in the second page it shows nothing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXJqS.png)

I am new with Mongodb functions so can you tell me how to fix this problem and display my data in 2 pages or more

Comment: why don't you use [$limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/), [$skip](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [$sort](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort) stages directly inside the aggregate?

Comment: I don't know how to use aggregate properly, I am new with mongodb functions